# I am having trouble defining and correcting a basic AI opponent for my Mangala Oware game

Tags: arrays, c, struct, artificial-intelligence

I need to develop atleast a basic AI for an Oware game. But the AI behaviour is not working like I wanted it to and I don't know where the problems lies.

```
typedef unsigned char t_Pit;

void show_AI(int winner, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[]) {
    char *str;
    if (winner == 1) {
        str = "AI Wins the game\n\n";
    } else if (winner == 0) {
        str = "You Win the game\n\n";
    } else {
        str = "Select pit (1-6): ";
    }

    printf(
        "\n"
        "----+-----AI-----+\n"
        "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "----+--------------+\n"
        "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "----+-----Player-----+\t"

        "\n %s",
        s[0], p[11], p[10], p[9], p[8], p[7], p[6], // NB: custom indexing
        s[1], p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5],
        str
    );
}

int T_Seeds ( int player, t_Pit p[] ) { //função para calcular o numero de sementes nas pits todas do jogador que queiramos
    int t = 0;
    int i;
    int start_p = ((player * 6) + 6) % 12;
    for ( i = start_p; i < (start_p + 6) ; i++ ) {
        t += p[i];
    }
    return t;
}

int main( void ) {
    enum { nPlayer = 2, nOne = 6, nPit = (2*nOne), nSeed = 4, nWin = 25 }; // ease of code

    int GameMode;
    int repeat = 0;
    while (repeat == 0){
        puts ( "Select game mode (0 for PlayervsPlayer, 1 for PlayervsAI): " );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &GameMode ) != 1 || GameMode > 1 ){
            puts ( "scanf failed, please try again\n" );
        } else {
            repeat = 1;
        }
    }
```

```
if (GameMode == 1){
        t_Pit score[ nPlayer ] = { 0 };
        t_Pit pit[ nPit ] = { 0 };
        int counter = 0;
        int counter1 = 0;
        int i;
        int y;
        int actv = 0;
        int end_con = 0;
        int winner = 2;

        for (i = 0; i < nPit; ++i) {
            pit[i] = nSeed;
        }

        for( ; score[0] < nWin && score[1] < nWin; actv = 0 ) {
            show_AI( winner, pit, score);
            
            int temp = pit[ actv ];
            for (i = actv; i < nOne; i++) { 
                if (temp < pit[i]){
                    temp = pit[i];
                }
            }
            
            int temp1 = pit[ nOne ]; /
            for (i = nOne; i < nPit; i++) { 
                if (temp1 < pit[i]){
                    temp1 = pit[i];
                }
            }

            int total_p = T_Seeds ( actv, pit );  
            int total_o = T_Seeds ( !actv, pit );
            
            for ( i = 0; i < nOne; i++ ) {
                if ( total_p == 1 && total_o == 1 && pit[i] == 1 && pit[i] == pit[i+6]) { 
                    puts ( "Infinite loop so it is a draw!\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            

            if ( temp == 0 ) { 
                puts ("Player has no seeds!\n");
                goto AIturn; //turno do oponente
            } 
            if ( temp1 == 0 ) { 
                counter1 = 0;
            } else counter1 = 1;  
    
            int from, to;
            while (counter == 0) { 
                if (counter1 == 1) { 
                    if ( scanf( "%d", &from ) != 1 || from < 1 || from > 6 || (pit[from - 1] <= 1 && temp > 1) || (pit[from - 1] == 0 && temp == 1) ) {
                        puts( "scanf failed, select pit (1-6): " );
                    } else {
                        counter = 1; //se scanf não falhar então sai do while
                    }
                }

                if (counter1 == 0) { 
                    for (i = actv; i < nOne; i++) {  
                        if ( (pit[i] >= (nOne - i) && (i != 5)) || (temp == 1 && pit[ 5 ] == 1) ) { 
                            end_con = 1;
                            break; 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (end_con == 0) { 
                        puts( "\n\nAi has no seeds and"
                                " no seeds can be given!");
                        for (i = actv; i < (nOne); i++) {
                            score[ actv ] += pit[ i ]; 
                            pit [ i ] = 0; 
                        }

                    
                        if ( score [actv] == 24) {
                            puts ("It's a draw!");
                            return 0;
                        } else {
                            winner = 0; 
                            goto Ending2; 
                        }
                    }

                    if ( scanf( "%d", &from ) != 1 || from < 1 || from > 6 || pit[from - 1] < (nOne + 1) - from || (pit[from - 1] <= 1 && temp > 1) || (pit[from - 1] == 0 && temp == 1)) { 
                        puts( "\n\nAI has no seeds!\n" );
                        puts( "scanf failed, select pit (1-6): " ); 
                    } else {
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            counter = 0; 
            counter1 = 0;
            from -= 1; 
            to = from;
            
            int nSow = pit[ from ];
            pit[ from ] = 0;

            while( nSow ) { //if more than 12 seeds, skip from pit
                if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != from ) {
                    ++pit[ to ];
                    --nSow;
                }
            }

            while( nSow-- ) 
                pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;
                

            for( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit ) // modulo -1
                if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                    score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                    pit[ to ] = 0;
                } else break;

            AIturn:

            temp = pit[ actv ]; 
            for (i = actv; i < nOne; i++) { 
                if (temp < pit[i]){
                    temp = pit[i]; 
                }
            }

            temp1 = pit[ nOne ]; 
            for (i = nOne; i < nPit; i++) { 
                if (temp1 < pit[i]){
                    temp1 = pit[i]; 
                }
            }

            total_p = T_Seeds ( actv, pit );  
            total_o = T_Seeds ( !actv, pit );
            
            for ( i = 0; i < nOne; i++ ) {
                if ( total_p == 1 && total_o == 1 && pit[i] == 1 && pit[i] == pit[i+6]) { 
                    puts ( "Infinite loop so it is a draw!\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            
            if ( temp == 0 ) { 
                 counter1 = 1;
            }

            if ( temp1 == 0 ) { 
                puts ("AI has no seeds!");
                continue;
            }

            if (counter1 == 1) { 
                for(i = actv; i < nOne; i++){
                    if (pit [i] <= 2){
                        for (y = nOne; y < nPit; y++){
                            if ( ( pit[y] > 1 || ( pit[y] == 1 && temp1 == 1) ) && ( ( pit[y] % 12 ) == ( ( nPit - y ) + i) ) ){
                                nSow = pit[y];
                                pit[y] = 0;
                                to = y;

                                while( nSow ) { 
                                    if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != y ) {
                                        ++pit[ to ];
                                        --nSow;
                                    }
                                }
                                while( nSow-- )
                                    pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

                                for( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit )
                                    if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                                        score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                                        pit[ to ] = 0;
                                    } else break;
                                counter = 1;
                                i = 6;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if (counter = 0){
                    for (y = (nPit - 1); y > (nOne - 1); y--) {
                        if (pit[y] >= 2){
                            nSow = pit[y];
                            pit[y] = 0;
                            to = y;
                            
                            while( nSow ) { 
                                if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != y ) {
                                    ++pit[ to ];
                                    --nSow;
                                    }
                                }
                            while( nSow-- )
                                pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

                            for( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit )
                                if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                                    score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                                    pit[ to ] = 0;
                                } else break;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (pit[y] == 1 && temp1 == 1){
                            nSow = pit[y];
                            pit[y] = 0;
                            to = y;

                            while( nSow ) { 
                                if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != y ) {
                                    ++pit[ to ];
                                    --nSow;
                                    }
                                }
                            while( nSow-- )
                                pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

                            for( ; to/nOne != y/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit )
                                if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                                    score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                                    pit[ to ] = 0;
                                } else break;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (counter1 == 0) {
                for (i = nOne; i < nPit; i++) {  
                    if ( (pit[i] >= (nPit - i) && (i != 11)) || (temp == 1 && pit[ 11 ] == 1) ) { 
                        end_con = 1; 
                        break; 
                    }
                }
                    
                if (end_con == 0) {
                    puts( "\n\nPlayer has no seeds and"
                            " no seeds can be given!");
                    for (i = nOne; i < nPit; i++) {
                        score[ !actv ] += pit[ i ]; 
                        pit [ i ] = 0;
                    }

                   
                    if ( score [actv] == 24) {
                        puts ("It's a draw!");
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        winner = 1; 
                        goto Ending2;
                    }
                }

                if (end_con) { 
                    for (y = (nPit - 1); y > (nOne - 1); y--){
                        if (pit[y] >= (nPit - y) && (y != 11)){
                            nSow = pit[y];
                            pit[y] = 0;
                            to = y;

                            while( nSow ) { 
                                if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != y ) {
                                    ++pit[ to ];
                                    --nSow;
                                    }
                                }
                            while( nSow-- )
                                pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

                            for( ; to/nOne != y/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit )
                                if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                                    score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                                    pit[ to ] = 0;
                                } else break;
                            counter = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (pit[y] == 1 && temp1 == 1 && counter == 0){
                        nSow = pit[y];
                        pit[y] = 0;
                        to = y;

                        while( nSow ) { 
                            if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != y ) {
                                ++pit[ to ];
                                --nSow;
                                }
                            }
                        while( nSow-- )
                            pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

                        for( ; to/nOne != y/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit )
                            if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                                score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                                pit[ to ] = 0;
                            } else break;
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            }
            
            if (score[0] >= nWin) {
                winner = 0;
                break;
            } else if (score[1] >= nWin) {
                winner = 1;
                break;
            }

        }

        Ending2:
        show_AI( winner, pit, score);
```

I tried to implement the AI to make 3 plays:

- Play to capture.
- In case it can't then play the rightmost pit.
- Play to give seeds to the player in case it has none and if possible.

I also tried to restrict those plays with the following rules:

- if it has a pit with 2 or more seeds, it cannot play a pit with 1 or less seeds.
- if it has only pits with one seed then allow it to pick the rightmost pit with a seed on it.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: After I choose 5 as my first move, the AI makes multiple moves before it passes the turn to the player again. @NathanJiang

Comment: AI shouldn't have unfettered access to the game, only the same interface as the player.  Ask it for the next turn, don't hand over control of the game engine

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @erik258, I will look into it the moment I manage to fix the AI and some math. I will also implement a printf of the move AI has chosen to take.